# Searchbar results not being clickable due to onBlur

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have got a searchbar, when the user searches the results show on a dropdown list...

Problem is I have got an onBlur event which when the user clicks away from the search box to any other element the display of the list changes to none.

The issue with this is that when the user clicks on a result its not the searchbar and the searchbar losses focus so it won't trigger the click on the li element of the search results.

```
onBlur={() => sethelpFocus(false)}
```

Sets the state to false which gives it the `className` which hides the element.

The only fix I have found to this has been to do this:

```
onBlur={() =>
  setTimeout(() => {
      sethelpFocus(false);
  }, 120)
}
```

As you can imagine, I do not like using timeouts as they seem to be a bit of a hack, it bassically gives the user time to click the element before it registers the unFocus also known as `onBlur`.

Any better ways of handling this?

Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: In your li onClick call e.stop​Propagation() this should stop the onBlur event from taking over.

Comment: @GifCo That doesn't seem to prevent `onblur`, could you post a demo?

Comment: Yes you are correct, blur and focus are a bit different than other events. The only way I can see without using setTimeout is using e.relatedTarget and checking if the id is the id of your dropdown list. warning relatedTarget only functions properly on inputs, to get it to work with other elements you need to add a tabIndex on the element (in this case your dropdown list) see here https://codepen.io/GifCo/pen/jRzKdv?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the search results on the input's `blur` event, hide them on the document's `click`.

That way, they will be hidden after the user clicks anywhere, but the element will have the chance to handle that click.

Comment: Due to usability, some users might not have a mouse to click, therefore tabbing out of focus should also take effect... What would you do for that scenario?

Comment: Listen for `keydown` event of the input, and hide the search results if it's a *Tab*.